# Xamarin Startup page not working

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I just installed Xamarin for Visual Studio. Whenever I try creating a new Android application, I just get a pop-up with a single tab

[image: 'GettingStarted.Xamarin']

I can't find any tab where I can write code. What should I do now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getting started page will appear when starting a Xamarin app, however you should still have the "Solution Explorer" pane.

You can either reopen it from the view menu, or with the key command Ctrl + Alt + L.

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the help .

Comment: Thanks! If it was helpful, please mark it as an answer so that it can also help others